# ENV variables not passing into node JS code from Docker

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I am running a sample code where I am parsing my env variables for mongoDB from docker run into my node js.

This is my current db config file

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoDbUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
let mongodb;

function connect(callback){
    mongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, (err, db) => {
        mongodb = db;
        callback();
    });
}
function get(){
    return mongodb;
}

function close(){
    mongodb.close();
}

module.exports = {
    connect,
    get,
    close
};
```

This is my Docker file

```
FROM node:latest
ENV MONGODB_URL=${MONGODB_URL}
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install 
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

In my server.js, I was testing where I could connect to the mongoDB URL parsed in

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
, MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, PORT = 4000
, instantMongoCrud = require('express-mongo-crud') // require the module
, express = require('express')
, app = express()
, path = require('path')
, options = { //specify options
    host: `localhost:${PORT}`
}
, db = require('./connection')


// connection to database
db.connect(() => {

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // add body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    // get function 
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        db.get().collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else
                res.render('../views/pages/index.ejs',{data:data});
        });
    });

    // post functions
    app.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
        var name=req.body.name
        var email=req.body.email
        var occupation=req.body.occupation
        var username=req.body.username

        console.log(name)
        console.log(email)

        db.get().collection('users').count({email : email}, function(err, result){
            console.log(result)
            if (result){
                console.log("user exists")
                res.send("user exists")
            }else{
                db.get().collection('users').save({name:name, email:email, occupation:occupation, username:username}, {w:1},function (err, result) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log("error")
                    } else{
                        console.log("success")
                        res.send("successful")
                    }        
                });
            }

        });


    });

    // delete user
    app.post('/deleteUser', function(req, res) {
        var email=req.body.email
        console.log(email)
        db.get().collection('users').deleteOne({email: email}, function(err,result){
            if (err){
                console.log("error")
            }else{
                console.log("successfully deleted user")
                res.send ("successfully deleted user")

            }

        });

    });

    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
        console.log('started');
        console.log(db)
    })

    app.use(instantMongoCrud(options)); // use for the instant Mongo CRUD 
});
```

I ran

```
docker run -e MONGODB_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/user' <containerID>
```

and hit a connection undefined issue.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null
    at /app/app.js:24:17
```

Is there any advice cause I thought that process.env would be able to grab the env value

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check env using `docker run -e MONGODB_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/user' <containerID>  env | grep MONGODB_URL`?

Comment: Hi yes

$ docker run -e MONGODB_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/user' 3e7e3c1fe510 env | grep MONGODB_URL
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/user

Comment: Is your local MongoDB also a docker container or just a normal installation?

Comment: hi @mihai, i am using a docker container for mongoDB. I also tried to do docker run -d -e "MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb/user" -p 4000:4000 e922a127d049 but it didnt work

Comment: Of course it didn't work because they are on different networks. You need to put them on the same network. I'll write a solution for it since it is more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both you application and your mongoDB instance run in containers it is easy to have them talk to each other by attaching them to the same network.

These are the steps:

```
#create a new network
docker network create app-network

#use your normal docker run for mongodb but add the --network flag
docker run --network app-network --name=mongodb ....

#run your app container on the same network
docker run --network app-network -d -e "MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb/user" -p 4000:4000 e922a127d049
```

If you are also familiar with docker-compose you can declare both services in a docker-compose.yml file and then they would automatically run on the same network, not need for you to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the container, localhost does not refer to your local machine. With iOS or Windows, you can fix this by replacing localhost with `host.docker.internal` in your `MONGODB_URL`. This will resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. If using Linux, you can instead use the flag `--network="host"` in `docker run`.

Comment: ahhh I see. I managed to get it working now with this:

docker run -d --network=mongo_db_default  --link=mongodb:mongodb -e "MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb/user" -p 4000:4000 <container ID>

Comment: Can I ask what if I want to access the mongoDB and if this mongoDB is running as a container on another machine i.e ec2 in aws?

Comment: I managed to get it: docker run -d --network=mongo_db_default  --link=mongodb:mongodb -e MONGODB_URL='mongodb://<ec2-ip>:27017/user' -p 4000:4000 e922a127d049